# Basic uniform convergence question

Tags: real-analysis

I am given that $f$ continuous in some neighbourhood of $0$...does $f(x/m)$ converge uniformly to $f(0)$ as $ m -> \infty$ ?

My attempt: 
$ f$ cnts about $0$ $ \implies $  for every $\epsilon >0$ $ \exists$ $\delta > 0$ ,
$ |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)| < \epsilon $
($ x \in R$)

So $|x/m| < \delta /m  \implies |f(x/m)-f(0)| < \epsilon $
Not quite sure where to go ...